# Magento Bundled product is not added to cart product_addtocart_form

Tags: magento

I have the problem that on a bundled product page where I present two products, the wrong product is added when you add the product to the cart by clicking on the image. If you click on the submit button the right product is added. 
I’ve been looking into the /checkout/cart files but can’t find anything.

Also I think it might have something to do with the action, but it can’t find the file where this function is written and don’t know what needs to be changed: 
`a href="[removed]void(0);" onclick="jQuery('#product_addtocart_form_27').submit()">'

For better explaining have a look on: 
http://www.plantastisch.nl/relatedproduct/index/index/pid/27/cid/16/?step=4 
You can choose between a white plant pot and a grey one. If you click on the image of the grey plant pot to add it to the cart it adds the white one. When you click on the submit button (’Kies’) it is added properly.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The page which you are talking about is a related product block which you can find here: `\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list\related.phtml`

So check in this file after  there is a form that is called in your file instead there is checkbox by default. So i cant tell you exactly what is the error in the action of that form. Just got the path to the file. So please check there if there is any error or any changes to be made.

Till then if i get any idea about the error i would let you know.

**EDIT:**

There is the problem in the id sent to the form.It sends same id for both products when clicked on the image. So can just append "_1" for first pot to the existing id that is sent now and "_2" for the second one.
Hope that might help you.